# How to get the very first date which will meet certain conditions bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to extract the very first date as seperate column (without duplicates) from joined table which will be after meeting the following condition: `ld.date between date(timestamp_seconds(sub.activated_at)) and current_date()`

Don't pay attention on the rest of the code.

I am trying to reach it as follows:

```
  SELECT 
  ...
  case when ld.date between date(timestamp_seconds(sub.activated_at)) and current_date() and l_row = 1
  then ld.date
  else null
  end as date_of_first_lead_after_sub
  from `jamesedition-152413.data_marts.chargebee_subscription` sub
  left join `jamesedition-152413.data_marts.pg_offices` off
  on cast(off.pipedrive_organization_id as int64) = cus.cf_pipedrive_organization_id
  left join (
  select office_id, date, count(1) as leads,
  row_number() over (partition by office_id
  order by date asc) as l_row
  from `jamesedition-152413.datasets.leads`
  where coalesce(Test_lead,false) = false
  group by 1,2) ld on ld.office_id = off.office_id and ld.date=p.date
  where sub.status = 'active' and sub.plan_id like 'elite%'
  group by ...
  order by activated_at desc
```

But it gives out a result with duplicate rows which contain different dates

Comment: What about `MAX(yourDateHere) OVER(...)`? See: [BigQuery - Aggregate functions in Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#max)

Comment: @MaciejLos do you mean in here `row_number() over (partition by office_id
  order by date asc) as l_row` ?

Comment: Yeah... Try it!

Comment: @MaciejLos i did it the other way `min(if(ld.date between date(timestamp_seconds(sub.activated_at)) and current_date(), ld.date, null)) as date_of_first_lead_after_subs`

Comment: No, you don't. Your statement does not contain `over` clause...

Comment: "Don't pay attention on the rest of the code.".  That is not good advice.  *Simplify the code when you write the question.*  Sample data and desired results would also help.

Comment: @MaciejLos even without `over` clause I got desired output, thanks!